How to handle user login through Spotify (what to do with tokens)
I'm trying to create a web app using a Django backend and React frontend. This is my first time using Django and dealing with accounts specifically. The app revolves around Spotify accounts so to login a user has to login through Spotify. I understand the authorization process and can get a user's access/refresh token, but I'm not sure what to do from here. I have found a lot of conflicting information online.
Most people say not to use local storage which makes sense. Right now I am trying to implement it using Django sessions, but I've read online about that not scaling well/not being RESTful so I'm confused. I also looked at using django-allauth and it worked, but I'm confused with how it would work with my React frontend because as far as I understand it, it's just something I can do only in Django (localhost:8000).
I want to be able to create a User in my database once a user logs in for the first time. From here, do I store the user's tokens inside the database too? Do I use Django's User model at all? I saw people mentioning Django's built-in authorization but confused how that ties in here.
I've tried using sessions and can do things after authenticating in the frontend, but unsure how to tie everything together with accounts.

You could store the username (or email, phone number, whatever Spotify provides) inside the database on first login, and also generate a token (maybe JWT) with an expiration time. Whenever the user authenticates through Spotify, if everything is okay, query the database for their Spotify username and return the JWT token. Other requests should require provisioning that token.

This question is similar to: Where to store JWT in browser? How to protect against CSRF?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
